# Windows Shell Context Menu recreated with qt

Tags: api, qt, shell, contextmenu, windows-explorer

Is there a way to query from qt the entries of the shell context menu (name and command)? Only if the application is run on Windows of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829644/winapi-call-context-menu-entry-provided-by-shell-extension), basically SHParseDisplayName+SHBindToParent to get IShellFolder, then call GetUIObjectOf on that to get [IContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That is the "native" way to do it, not sure if qt has any wrappers you can use.